# Techniques to mobile geolocation

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, geolocation, wifi, ip-geolocation

I'm writing a paper about ways/procedures/techniques to geolocate mobile phones.

So far I'm stuck with Bluetooth. Can anyone please give me other ideas and webs where I can research them and finish my paper?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on [mobile phone tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking):

- Cell tower triangulation
- GPS in the phone

Answer (score 1):

Cell tower triangulation has many forms. Some rely upon received signal strength (RSSI).  Some rely upon RSSI and angle of arrival to position without cooperating among towers.

GPS in the phone is voluntary, except for E-911 services.

In principle, there is content-based geolocation, if the download stream being provided can be mined for textual hints or type of content which give clues on geolocation.  That may sound lame -- it really isn't -- but many IP geolocation systems infer positions based upon hostnames recovered using reverse DNS of last hops along traceroutes to a client. Thus, if "SFO" is containing in the hostname, they may infer "San Francisco". It's not lame because the tags can be mutually filtered, all from a page, and then temporally.

I'd recommend doing some digging on these rather than just parroting what I've written, especially regarding their pitfalls.